# Add a display to let user wait in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-script

I am looking for a pretty stupid piece of code for bash that will show a kind of "please wait" rolling display, with the characters : - \ | /

The first problem is that I don't know the name of this thing, so it is a bit difficult to find, and the other is could you please provide a scriptlet please ?

Thank you in advance,

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the valuable help.
I had a look at all pieces of code, and they all seem pretty long for what I am doing.

So based on that I just redid a tiny piece of code I am sharing with you.

```
#! /bin/bash
state=1
delay=0.5
printf "-"
sleep $delay

while [ 1 ]
do
        printf "\b"
        case $state in
                0) printf "-";;
                1) printf "\\";;
                2) printf "|";;
                3) printf "/";;
        esac
        if [ $state -eq 3 ]
        then
                state=0;
        else
                state=$((state+1));
        fi
        sleep $delay
done
```

Of course, this can work as a standalone code, but take out the bash line, and you can insert it easily in a script, and eventually shrink it a bit more.
The only thing is about the condition, which is now running forever, so have to get out your own condition for the stop.

Hope you'll find it useful. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They're called 'spinners'. Linux Journal has an [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-bash-spinner) with example code.

Comment: Can you please include the answer here? Otherwise your post would become obsolete when the link goes down.

Comment: I didn't post the answer because (a) it's quite a number of lines of code (especially if additional documentation is included) and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to copy them, (b) this SE isn't specifically about coding and (c) I thought the main question was 'what are these things called'

Comment: You could point to the archive.org copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20130405162038/http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-bash-spinner instead. That is much less likely to go away.

Comment: Pointing to an archive is one thing, but in essence we don't want users having to go somewhere else to get an answer. The OP also asked for a script if possible. Of course this is not Stack Overflow but that doesn't mean it's not allowed to post code in your answers :)

Comment: His 'first problem' was what these things were called. I answered that. I'm happy to remove the link if that makes it any better. I'm not copying some code I can't take credit for or pointing to a site (partially) copying that site, in my opinion that's disrespectful towards the original author.

Answer (score 0):

They're also called 'Throbbers'. For an implementation plus explanation how to use it see http://fitnr.com/showing-a-bash-spinner.html (disclaimer: I haven't tested it myself, but I overlooked it and it looks reasonable)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below code for "please wait" process bar / spinners.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo -e "Please wait ..."
 while true;
 do
 echo -ne '-\r'
 sleep .2
 echo -ne '\\\r'
 sleep .2
 echo -ne '|\r'
 sleep .2
 echo -ne '/''\r'
 sleep .2
 echo -ne '-\r'
 done
```

or

try

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo -n "Please wait..."
 while true
 do
      echo -n "."
      sleep .2
 done
```

Its working for me...